# In eigenfaces decomposition, should the images be converted to grayscale?

Tags: pca, image-processing

I'm working on a project about using Eigenfaces for classification: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse455/10wi/projects/p2/ . But in here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pmuthuku/mlsp_page/assignments/assignment2_hints.html it says that the image needs to be converted to grayscale. Is this true? The first link does not say anything about that.

Comment: Do you see colored images in the first link? No. And there is also ```PCA is a technique by which we reduce the dimensionality of data points. For example, consider the space of all 20-by-30 pixel grayscale images.```. Nothing explicit. But interpret for yourself. (Without customized models, color-information is usually not really helping in such a modestly complex framework)

Comment: @sascha Thank you , I have fixed the problem :) :)